# I've made a program in C that takes two inputs, x and n, and raises x to the power of n. 10^10 doesn't work, what happened?

Tags: c, recursion, cs50, exponent

I've made a program in C that takes two inputs, x and n, and raises x to the power of n. 10^10 doesn't work, what happened?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float isEven(int n)
{
    return n % 2 == 0;
}

float isOdd(int n)
{
    return !isEven(n);
}

float power(int x, int n)
{
    // base case
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    // recursive case: n is negative
    else if (n < 0)
    {
        return (1 / power(x, -n));
    }
    // recursive case: n is odd
    else if (isOdd(n))
    {
        return x * power(x, n-1);
    }
    // recursive case: n is positive and even
    else if (isEven(n))
    {
        int y = power(x, n/2);
        return y * y;
    }
    
    return true;
}

int displayPower(int x, int n)
{
    printf("%d to the %d is %f", x, n, power(x, n));
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("What will be the base number?");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    
    int n = 0;
    printf("What will be the exponent?");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    displayPower(x, n);
}
```

For example, here is a pair of inputs that works:

```
./exponentRecursion 
What will be the base number?10
What will be the exponent?9
10 to the 9 is 1000000000.000000
```

But this is what I get for 10^10:

```
./exponentRecursion 
What will be the base number?10
What will be the exponent?10
10 to the 10 is 1410065408.000000
```

Why does this write such a weird number?

BTW, 10^11 returns 14100654080.000000, exactly ten times the above.

Perhaps it may be that there is some "Limit" to the data type that I am using? I am not sure.

Comment: You are mixing `float`s and `int`s in weird and not-so-wonderful ways. You need first of all to decide whether you are computing a `float` or and `int`, and then consistently use the correct type for all calculations.

Comment: `int y = power(x, n/2);` This converts a float to an integer. You then `return y * y;` which is an integer multiplication. But integer multiplication cannot go as high as 10^10. It maxes out at around 2 * 10^9.

Comment: It can't!? So there is a limit. 
As dbush suggested, doubles would be better then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable x is an `int` type.  The most common internal representation of that is 32 bits.  That a signed binary number, so only 31 bits are available for representing a magnitude, with the usual maximum positive int value being 2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647.  Anything larger that that will overflow, giving a smaller magnitude and possibly a negative sign.

For a greater range, you can change the type of x to `long long` (usually 64 bits--about 18 digits) or `double` (usually 64 bits, with 51 bits of precision for about 15 digits).

(Warning: Many implementations use the same representation for `int` and `long`, so using `long` might not be an improvement.)

Answer (score 0):

A `float` only has enough precision for about 7 decimal digits.  Any number with more digits than that will only be an approximations.

If you switch to `double` you'll get about 16 digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

When you start handling large numbers with the *basic* data types in C, you can run into trouble.

Integral types have a limited range of values (such as 4x10<sup>9</sup> for a 32-bit unsigned integer). Floating point type haver a much larger range (though not infinite) but limited precision. For example, IEEE754 double precision can give you about 16 decimal digits of precision in the range +/-10<sup>308</sup>

To recover *both* of these aspects, you'll need to use a bignum library of some sort, such as [MPIR](http://mpir.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are mixing different data types in a C program, there are several implicit casts done by the compiler. As there are strong rules how the compiler works one can exactly figure out, what happens to your program and why.

As I do not know all of this casting rules, I did the following: Estimating the maximum of precision needed for the biggest result. Then casting explicit every variable and funktion in the process to this precision, even if it is not necessary. Normally this will work like a workarount.